# Como representar varios valores con uno solo en un parametro de un SP SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedure, parametros

tengo el siguiente procedimiento almacenado:

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE sp_Prueba
@UserID varchar(100),
@Report varchar(100),
@Setting varchar(100),
@Value varchar(max),
@DateStart date,
@DateEnd date,
@cur_clave_str varchar(250)
AS
BEGIN       

    DECLARE @res varchar(max)= NULL     
    --TABLA TEMPORAL CON UNA COLUMNA
    DECLARE @t TABLE (resultado VARCHAR(MAX))
    --INSERTAR DATOS A TABLA TEMPORAL
    INSERT INTO @t 
    exec spu_SetUserSetting @UserID, @Report, @Setting, @Value
    --exec spu_SetUserSetting 'AMERICAS','Ejemplo','TestParam','4073455,4082850'
    --ASIGNANDO EL VALOR DE LA COLUMNA A LA VARIABLE.
    SELECT @res=resultado FROM @t
    --select @res
        
    exec [LinkedServer].[BaseDatosRemota].[esquema].[NombreProcedimiento]
        @DateStart = @DateStart,
        @DateEnd = @DateEnd, 
        @cur_clave_str = @cur_clave_str,
        @emp_clave_str = @res --emp_clave                       
END
GO

exec sp_Prueba 'AMERICAS','Ejemplo','TestParam', '10562,10980,1059806,1163108', '2023-01-01', '2023-05-18', @cur_clave_str
```

Y me gustaria preguntarles como puedo remplazar el 4 valor que recibe mi sp por un valor abreviado? es decir en vez de utilizar siempre este parametro '10562,10980,1059806,1163108' remplazarlo por algo como 115 y este 115 al ingresarlo como parametro nos hace referencia que estamos usando los valores anteriores, como se puede observar en mi sp tambien tengo un sp que me ayuda a guardar estos valores en una tabla pero no se como realizar lo que les mencione, les agredeceria mucho si me pudieran ayudar sobre como realizarlo, Gracias!

Comment: ¿Como planeas diferenciar entre el hecho de que 115 se refiere a un conjunto de valores y no a un valor en sí?

Comment: cuál es la relación entre 115 y ese parámetro de muestra que nos compartiste? cómo debería suponer que 115 equivale a `10562,10980,1059806,1163108`? Qué quieres decir con _valores anteriores_?

Comment: @LuisCazares era un ejemplo, tambien se podria representar el conjunto de valores con algun nombre

Comment: @Alfabravo su relacion es que 115 representará el conjunto de valores, y para que sepas como 115 equivale a 10562,10980,1059806,1163108' es lo que aun no determino por eso pedi su ayuda. A lo que me refiero a "valores anteriores" es a estos valores 10562,10980,1059806,1163108

Comment: @LuisCazares ya entendi bien tu pregunta, creo que seria cambiando el tipo de parametro que recibe, tengo pensado en guardar el conjunto de datos en una tabla y de ahi tomar los valores pero lo que me falta es como representar ese conjunto de valores con un nombre y usarlo como parametro

Comment: ¿qué tal `if @param = '115' set @param = '123,456,789,012'`?

Answer (score 0):

En tu pregunta propones un problema abierto que admite diversas soluciones y muestras el código de un procedimiento almacenado que despliega otras operaciones que se escaparían del ámbito de un [ejemplo mínimo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), completo y verificable en Stack Overflow.

Por ceñirme al núcleo de tu pregunta, que podría resumirse en "Cómo simplificar o codificar información compleja en un dato pasado como argumento a un procedimiento almacenado", la manera más habitual de hacer esto es crear una tabla de CONFIGURACIÓN que mapee información compleja como las listas a las que haces referencia a un valor identificador o una etiqueta o label más sencilla.

Puesto que no es posible trazar toda la información y procedimientos de tu ejemplo, he decidido crear desde cero un caso completo que hace uso de una tabla semejante de configuración para mapear listas de datos con identificadores simples, y diseñar un procedimiento almacenado que trata esta información basándose en los argumentos que recibe, para llenar una segunda tabla desagregando los datos de las listas.

Este es el código completo con las sentencias SQL Server DDL y DML que permiten reproducir y someter a prueba el ejemplo:

```sql
-- Creación de la tabla de configuración-mapeo CONF_AnimalsGroup
CREATE TABLE CONF_AnimalsGroup (
    Id INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
    AnimalsGroupCode INT,
    AnimalsGroupType VARCHAR(100),
    AnimalsGroupList VARCHAR(MAX)
);

-- Inserción de registros en la tabla de configuración
INSERT INTO CONF_AnimalsGroup (AnimalsGroupCode, AnimalsGroupType, AnimalsGroupList)
VALUES
    (101, 'Reptile', 'Caimán Anaconda Iguana Cocodrilo Galápago'),
    (102, 'Mammal', 'Elefante Tigre León Oso Mono'),
    (103, 'Bird', 'Águila Cóndor Flamenco Pingüino Loro'),
    (104, 'Insect', 'Abeja Mosquito Hormiga Mariquita Escarabajo'),
    (105, 'Fish', 'Tiburón Salmón Pez_Payaso Bacalao Trucha');

-- Creación de la tabla destino del procedimiento, VeterinaryEvaluation
CREATE TABLE VeterinaryEvaluation (
    Id INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
    ZooCode INT,
    VeterinaryCode INT,
    EvaluationDate DATE,
    EvaluationPassed BIT,
    Animal1 VARCHAR(100),
    Animal2 VARCHAR(100),
    Animal3 VARCHAR(100),
    Animal4 VARCHAR(100),
    Animal5 VARCHAR(100)
);
```

```sql
-- Creación del procedimiento almacenado
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[CreateVeterinaryEvaluation]
    @ZooCode INT,
    @VeterinaryCode INT,
    @AnimalsCode INT,
    @VeterinaryEvaluation BIT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @AnimalsGroupList VARCHAR(MAX);

    -- Obtiene la lita AnimalsGroupList en función del argumento AnimalsCode
    SELECT @AnimalsGroupList = AnimalsGroupList
    FROM CONF_AnimalsGroup
    WHERE AnimalsGroupCode = @AnimalsCode;

    -- Divide la lista AnimalsGroupList en los nombres individuales de sus componentes
    DECLARE @AnimalTable TABLE (Animal VARCHAR(100));

    INSERT INTO @AnimalTable (Animal)
    SELECT value
    FROM STRING_SPLIT(@AnimalsGroupList, ' ');

    -- Almacenamiento en variables de los nombres individuales de animales
    -- guardados en la tabla @AnimalTable en el paso anterior
    DECLARE @Animal1 VARCHAR(100), @Animal2 VARCHAR(100), @Animal3 VARCHAR(100), @Animal4 VARCHAR(100), @Animal5 VARCHAR(100);

    SELECT 
        @Animal1 = Split.a.value('/x[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)'),
        @Animal2 = Split.a.value('/x[2]', 'VARCHAR(100)'),
        @Animal3 = Split.a.value('/x[3]', 'VARCHAR(100)'),
        @Animal4 = Split.a.value('/x[4]', 'VARCHAR(100)'),
        @Animal5 = Split.a.value('/x[5]', 'VARCHAR(100)')
    FROM (
        SELECT CAST('<x>' + REPLACE(@AnimalsGroupList, ' ', '</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML) AS Animals
    ) AS A
    CROSS APPLY Animals.nodes('/x') AS Split(a);

    -- Creación de un nuevo registro en la tabla VeterinaryEvaluation
    INSERT INTO VeterinaryEvaluation (ZooCode, VeterinaryCode, EvaluationDate, EvaluationPassed, Animal1, Animal2, Animal3, Animal4, Animal5)
    VALUES (@ZooCode, @VeterinaryCode, GETDATE(), @VeterinaryEvaluation, @Animal1, @Animal2, @Animal3, @Animal4, @Animal5);
END;
```

Uso del procedimiento almacenado:

```sql
EXEC CreateVeterinaryEvaluation @ZooCode = 63, @VeterinaryCode = 8366, @AnimalsCode = 102, @VeterinaryEvaluation = 1;
EXEC CreateVeterinaryEvaluation @ZooCode = 63, @VeterinaryCode = 8366, @AnimalsCode = 103, @VeterinaryEvaluation = 1;
EXEC CreateVeterinaryEvaluation @ZooCode = 40, @VeterinaryCode = 8366, @AnimalsCode = 101, @VeterinaryEvaluation = 0;
```

```swift
+----+---------+----------------+----------------+------------------+----------+----------+----------+-----------+----------+
| Id | ZooCode | VeterinaryCode | EvaluationDate | EvaluationPassed | Animal1  | Animal2  | Animal3  |  Animal4  | Animal5  |
+----+---------+----------------+----------------+------------------+----------+----------+----------+-----------+----------+
|  1 |      63 |           8366 | 2023-05-19     |                1 | Elefante | Tigre    | León     | Oso       | Mono     |
|  2 |      63 |           8366 | 2023-05-19     |                1 | Águila   | Cóndor   | Flamenco | Pingüino  | Loro     |
|  3 |      40 |           8366 | 2023-05-19     |                0 | Caimán   | Anaconda | Iguana   | Cocodrilo | Galápago |
+----+---------+----------------+----------------+------------------+----------+----------+----------+-----------+----------+
```

Como se puede deducir del código, el propósito de este ejemplo es crear un procedimiento almacenado `CreateVeterinaryEvaluation` que permite insertar registros de evaluaciones clínicas de determinados grupos de animales realizadas por veterinarios, utilizando la información de los animales almacenada en la tabla de configuración `CONF_AnimalsGroup` y guardando las evaluaciones (cuyo sentido positivo o negativo se representa mediante un booleano BIT) en la tabla de destino `VeterinaryEvaluation`.

Trabajar con listas no suele ser una buena idea en bases de datos relacionales si puedes diseñar otra solución, pero en este caso he empleado esta forma de trabajo y mostrado la manera de dividir esas listas en sus componentes porque este parece ser uno de los requisitos o necesidades de tu propuesta.

En mi ejemplo, el mapeo de las listas de animales lo realizo al identificador `AnimalsGroupCode`, pero podría hacerse también a un campo de texto como por ejemplo aquí `AnimalsGroupType`, suponiendo que fuese único. El objetivo sigue siendo el mismo: mapear en una tabla de configuración determinada información compleja a un dato más simple y utiilzar este último como parámetro configurador del procedimiento almacenado.